# JSON Deserialize Object not working

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have the following problem:

```
(UserAttribues)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"username\":\"Someone\"}");
```

throws an Error:

```
"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'UserAttribues'."
```

The class is simple as:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class UserAttribues
 {
    public string username;
 }
```

Any help appreciated. (I also tried "{\"username\":\"\"Someone\"\"}")

Comment: Did you try the generic version? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserAttributes>(...`

Comment: oh that actually worked... Can you explain why? (if you post as an answer ill accept it)

Comment: I don't want to steal the answer from @StarterPack, but it is because you are specifically telling it the type you want and it will do its best to map the fields. With a cast you rely on type compatibility. C# doesn't just know how to map type members between any two types.

Comment: All right, thanks a lot for help and explanation, makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use JsonConvert.Deserialize for this.
Use it like this:

```
 var attr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserAttribues>("{\"username\":\"Someone\"}");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use the non-generic version of the DeserializeObject() method you get a JObject. As the error shows, you cannot cast this JObject to a UserAttributes object. The reason is that type casting is allowed in specific cases, like casting between compatible primitive types (e.g. between `int` and `double`) or between classes which are related.

For example, if we have a base class and a derived class, `class Animal` and `class Reptile : Animal`, you can safely cast an object of type Reptile to Animal, or the other way around (if your object is indeed a Reptile, otherwise you'll get an error).

Therefore, the reason your sample code doesn't work is because the JObject you have and the UserAttributes you want to get aren't related in any way. The solution, as already pointed out by @StarterPack, is to use the generic version `DeserializeObject<some_type>()`.